# Network interface names on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, network-programming, xamarin.ios

I use the following code to get a list of network interfaces currently available on the iPhone:

```
NetworkInterface[] l__objNetworkInterfaceList = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

foreach (NetworkInterface l__objNetworkInterface in l__objNetworkInterfaceList)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Name: " + l__objNetworkInterface.Name);
}
```

l__objNetworkInterface.Name returns a short string which identifies the Interface (e.g. lo0 for loopback, en0 for WiFi, pdp_ip for cellular, and so on). But i get some names i can't figure out which type of interface they specify:

```
ap0
gif0
stf0
```

Does anyone know this interface types? Is there a documentation where the interfaces are listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `git` is for tunnels in the *BSD (including OSX, iOS) worlds;
- `stf` is for six-to-four (IPv6 to IPv4);
- not quite sure about `ap0`... I was thinking it could be a typo for `tap0` but it seems to be a [bridge](http://jorudolph.wordpress.com/2011/07/22/ios-detect-personal-hotspot/) between `en0` and `pdp_ip0` (i.e. wifi to 3g) which would make a lot of sense;

You can google [books](http://www.6net.org/book/deployment-guide.pdf) about the subject if you want to know more details.